# Video Export based on location instead of based on time

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to export a video but I got a sketchy video that sort all the images from the collection based on time and show the separately instead of put them together. where I'm doing it wrong folks?

this is the output : 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G_I_EJd7RIRXnQds3v1Z26wojSHIrHMj

and this is my code:

```
var geometry = 
    /* color: #00ffff */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[43.13951370225977, 39.96689872963192],
          [43.13951370225977, 35.55713058691435],
          [48.30308792100977, 35.55713058691435],
          [48.30308792100977, 39.96689872963192]]], null, false),
    region = 
    /* color: #bf04c2 */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[44.916054138206086, 38.262521328466725],
          [44.916054138206086, 37.07114389380858],
          [46.047645935081086, 37.07114389380858],
          [46.047645935081086, 38.262521328466725]]], null, false),
    l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA"),
    params = {"opacity":1,"bands":["B4","B3","B2"],"min":0.07534788794392866,"max":0.3955488244032345,"gamma":1.239};

var collection = l8.filterBounds(geometry)
                    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'LESS_THAN', 30)
                    .filterDate('1999-01-01', '2020-01-01');

//var l8med = collection.median();
Map.addLayer(collection, params, 'Layer');

print(collection.size());

//var newimg = l8med.visualize(params); 

Export.video.toDrive({
  collection: collection.map(function (image) { return image.visualize(params); }),
  description: 'a2',
  dimensions: 720,
  framesPerSecond: 12,
  folder: "GEE",
  maxFrames: 100000,
  region: region
});
```

Comment: Actually, I'm now trying to export videos of each WRS block separately and import them to preview and make the bigger picture! I know it's not the best solution for a programmer but I am not a programmer though.

Comment: I found part of the answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280156/mosaicking-a-image-collection-by-date-day-in-google-earth-engine
but still